# Can we use geogebra as a "drawing software"?

Tags: software-recommendation

I am interested in using [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic), which is a geometry software, as a drawing software. I suppose this would save me a lot of time as a replacement for drawing directly in tikz.
The options I miss most are *selection* (as in say gimp), and simple *copy & paste*.

Geogebra allows to make a copy of an object as a reflection/translation/rotation; so changing the copy is not possible.  I would sometimes prefer to make a simple duplicate copy. A work-around I found was to copy from one window to another. This is not working well either (for geogebra, objects have geometrical coordinates).

Is there a way to get a simple duplicate copy (not as auxiliary object) in geogebra? Or should I rather stop trying to use geogebra as a drawing software?

Comment: I would prefer geogebra because i can export to tikz.

Comment: Hi, maybe you'll have better luck asking about this on one of the mathy stacks like https://math.stackexchange.com/ or even https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/, since there might be more people with any actual experience with geogebra. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to all. I posted the same question in math.se ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3834419/120721)) (couldn't find a way to move this question).

Comment: @CyriacAntony dont multipost. Choose one or the other.

Comment: If "applicationX" fits your needs.. use it... There's no such thing as "application police" who enforce using a specific set of apps for a specific task.

Comment: "Can I draw with X?" ...if it leaves a mark, [yes](https://twitter.com/boubou_design/status/1298412937896484867)

Comment: .. or you could just use some guys socks with white paint to cover up an existing painting, film it, then reverse the video. (Note in the animation.. the socks are *white* on the bottom when it starts, but miraculously we're lead to believe they paint dark)

Answer (score 0):

It is a trade-of. When you have a application geared to make indirect modeling you usually don't want to introduce too many direct modeling features, because it dilutes the meaning of your application. Pretty soon you have direct modeling application that has obscure indirect features.*

Geogebra is a indirect modeler where the purpose is to tell the computer how to draw geometric constructions.

If you want direct modeling features use Inkscape, Illustrator, Gravit or affinity designer.

So now all you need to decide is if you need direct modeling more or less, or wether you can add even one more software in your toolset.

* Indirect modeling is always a bit unintuitive as the goal is to gain something by not directly doing what you want to accomplish to get gains at a later date by having the indirect structre to fall back on.

Comment: There was an era when persons who wanted to know how some drawing can be constructed in Illustrator, Inkscape etc... got at least once suggestion "you can write a script!" or "write it in a text editor". The indirect modelling was considered as a good virtue just like the working method of composers like Mozart, Beethoven, Sibelius etc... They worked with pen and paper.

Comment: @user287001 there is some merit to not doing things directly. Theres no reason indirect means write a script. Though that is one possible indirect way. The main problem with direct is that should you wish to do a lot of limited changes you would need in certain cases redo all your work. But straightfoward has also merit, you just dont gain any investent benefit, but also no setup cost.

Comment: Perhaps the most common indirect modeling method for graphic designers is using styles in indesign. This is really powerful. But quite many people do not get why you would bother.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that inkscape had an export to tikz option.

Comment: @CyriacAntony it dies not but you can export eos which is the same thing